# Fallo en Dialog Flow : No responses defined for platform: DIALOGFLOW_CONSOLE

Tags: nodejs, dialogflow

Trabajando con Google Dialog Flow, con alguna de sus actualizaciones me ha dejado de funcionar el uso del fullfilment en el Bot desde la consola de Dialog Flow. Si ataco al bot desde otro gestor (Zendesk, GIA,...) me funciona correctamente.

El error que me da es :  No responses defined for platform: DIALOGFLOW_CONSOLE

Las versiones que uso en el fullfilment son:

{
"name": "dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
"description": "This is the default fulfillment for a Dialogflow agents using Cloud Functions for Firebase",
"version": "0.0.1",
"private": true,
"license": "Apache Version 2.0",
"author": "Google Inc.",
"engines": {
"node": "10"
},
"scripts": {
"start": "firebase serve --only functions:dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
"deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions:dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment"
},
"dependencies": {
**"actions-on-google": "^2.4.1",
"firebase-admin": "~6.0.0",
"firebase-functions": "^2.1.0",
"dialogflow": "^0.6.0",
"dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.6.1",**
}
}

El problema lo da cuando llamo a la función de setFollowupEvent en el fullfilment

agent.setFollowupEvent('questionMain_EVENT');

Answer (score 0):

Después de mucho investigar, he descubierto que invocando la la función de setFollowupEvent de la siguiente manera, no da el error al trabajar desde la consola de Dialog Flow

agent.setFollowupEvent({ "name": "darTemperatura_EVENT"});